# Getting Error in listing publication data

Tags: core-service

In CMS there are many publications and some of them are giving following error while accessing them:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011:GetSystemWideListResult. The InnerException message was 'Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536'. Change the object graph or increase the MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota. '. Please see InnerException for more details.
>   Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536'. Change the object graph or increase the MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota."

Any idea what is causing the issue ?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your publication has a lot of items. So you get a  WCF error due to the size. Here you go:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191167/maximum-number-of-items-that-can-be-serialized-or-deserialized-in-an-object-grap

Comment: Your answer is more appropriate as it also contain link to the question that I have mentioned :)

Comment: I think it's clear what the issue is - the main challenge is: which configuration files need to be modified?

Comment: Suppose I change the configuration value to Max and that too in right configuration file but still what if SDL code  doesn't support more than '65536' . I meant what if in sdl code int variable has been used? Would configuration change still work? Our team tried to resolved using configuration change but couldn't do so until we received patch from SDL.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check for the value of `maxItemsInObjectGraph` attribute in the service behaviour.

A sample would look like this:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="<your value>" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

You may want to check this question over the Stackoverflow:

[how-to-fix-maxitemsinobjectgraph-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298209/how-to-fix-maxitemsinobjectgraph-error/6298356#6298356)

Comment: This was first failed step our team took to resolve the issue.